# How can I exclude a category in a Pentaho Report Designer column chart?

Tags: pentaho

I need to create a column chart that includes most, but not all, categories from my data set. For example, my data set's categories are {x, y, z} and I need the column chart to display data only for {x,y}. How can I do this in Pentaho Report Designer (PRD)?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't - you have to make sure the dataset is what PRD expects to display.  But I'll watch this with interest to see if there is a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully excluded a data point in my Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) column chart by doing the following:

1. Create an Open Formula function:
   `=if([category_name]= "value to be excluded";null(); [category_name])`
2. In the Chart settings where category column is set, select the function you just created as the category.